# TypeError: String Indices must be integers; Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, json, string, integer

Recently I downloaded and attempted to use an open source device which has had it's support shut down for quite some time. When I attempt to run the program I get the error "TypeError: String Indices must be integers".
Ive had a look around for a solution but as python is not something Im accustomed to, I think the solutions are going over my head, or do not suit my issue.

The Full Error Code:

```
File "e621dl.py, line 93, in <module>
   Current_page, defailt.MAX_RESULTS>
File "..\e621_api.py" line 30, in get_posts uploads.append(UPLOAD(post['file_url], post['md5], post['file_ext']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

Firstly I apologise for my incompitance if this is a really really easy fix, and secondly, Here is the code;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from json import loads
from support import SpoofOpen
from collections import namedtuple
import logging

UPLOAD = namedtuple('Upload', 'url md5 ext')
SPOOF = SpoofOpen()

LIST_BASE = 'https://e621.net/post/index.json?'
TAGS = 'tags='
DATE = ' date:>'
PAGE = '&page='
MAX = '&limit='

def get_posts(search_term, uploaded_after, page_num, max_results):
    request = LIST_BASE + \
        TAGS + search_term + \
        DATE + str(uploaded_after) + \
        PAGE + str(page_num) + \
        MAX + str(max_results)

    log = logging.getLogger('e621_api')
    log.debug('search url = ' + request)
    results = loads(SPOOF.open(request).read().decode())

    uploads = []
    for post in results:
        uploads.append(UPLOAD(post['file_url'], post['md5'], post['file_ext']))
    return uploads

def download(url, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as dest:
        source = SPOOF.open(url)
        dest.write(source.read())
```

Comment: What's the value of `post`?

Comment: If Im not mistaken Post is defined in the line 

`uploads.append(UPLOAD(post['file_url'], post['md5'], post['file_ext']))`
 
File_url is a string of 6 numbers, md5 is the md5 hash of the post, and the file_ext is extension of the file being downloaded. I forgot to mention it's an image downloader if that makes any differance in the solution.

Comment: NSFW. NSFW. NSFW. You should warn us, at least.

Comment: I mean, by `results = loads(SPOOF.open(request).read().decode())` I know that `results` should be a json object. And by `for post in results` I know that `results` should be a json array which is iterable. And `post` should be a json object. But what is an example value of `post`?

Comment: @lian I never said you had to go to the site that is being downloaded from, Also; It doesnt have to be NSFW.
@skyline75489 An Example value would be `628458'

Comment: @skyline75489, just go to the `LIST_BASE` and see the data format.

Comment: Have you tried `print(post)` to see what it is ?

Comment: On the posted traceback, the problem line is missing two single quotes - one after ```file_url``` and ```md5```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using this particular tool, I ran into this error when specifying more than 6 tags at a time per line. Reducing the number of tags per line/search in the tags.txt file to 6 tags resolved this error for me.